# How to set custom title hint on drawingControlOptions buttons?

Tags: google-maps

When I do `mouseover` on `drawingControl` buttons a default title hint text appears, e.g. "Draw a shape", "Stop drawing", etc. You can see those buttons here http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/11/make-your-map-interactive-with-shape.html

How to change that text to some custom text?

Answer (score 1):

Have you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474604/is-it-possible-to-change-the-google-maps-drawing-manager-icons) ?

With a little bit of jQuery, you can select your image and change attributes, like its href or its text.
Just select `.gmnoprint` class and, in your case, change the `title` attribute