# How to change google maps Drawing Manager toolbar tooltip?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a situation with google map drawing manager. I want to change the drawing manager toolbar default tooltip. When we move mouse over the drawing manager tool bar(moving mouse over marker,circle)we see that tooltip "Add a Marker", "Draw a circle" . I want to change the toolbar tooltip as " Add New Location " , " Draw a Area" . I use google map API version3. Is it possible to change it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nodes for the buttons are not accessible via the API, the best way would be to ommit the built-in controls and create your own instead.

Another approach(using jQuery, but it would be possible without a framework too):

```
$(map.getDiv()).one('mouseover','img[src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/drawing.png"]',function(e){

    $(e.delegateTarget).find('img[src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/drawing.png"]').each(function(){
      $(this).closest('div[title]').attr('title',function(){
         switch(this.title){
          case 'Add a marker':
            return 'Add New Location';
              break;
          case 'Draw a circle':
            return 'Draw an area';
              break;
          default:return this.title;  
         } 

      });
    });
  });
```

It observes the mouseover-event of the buttons(because you'll never know when the buttons available inside the document) and then modifies the title.

But this approach will only work when the API uses english as language. To achieve it regardless  of the language you'll have to check the top-property of the button-image(this seems to be the only detail that may be used to determine the type of shape the button is used for)

Comment: @@ Dr. Molle : Thanks Molle. It worked well as I expected. Thanks a lot for such a sweet code.

Comment: How to implement this. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

For what ever were the reasons, I couldn't get the @Dr.Molle version to work.   However adapting the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474604/is-it-possible-to-change-the-google-maps-drawing-manager-icons/13685786) I was able to get it to work in my application.

For example I simply wanted to change the text of the `DrawingManager' drawRectangle method and the code below worked for me.  The crucial thing with this modification to the DrawingManager tooltip is to make sure the document and map objects are full loaded before this code runs.

```
        $(".gmnoprint").each(function(){
        var newObj = $(this).find("[title='Draw a rectangle']");
        newObj.attr('title', 'Draw a rectangle around the area to search');
    });
```